# Pointing out to common path in weblogic for logs in clusterted environment

Tags: logging, weblogic, load-balancing

i have two nodes in cluster , from my application i want to access the logs and show in UI , but the problem is , how to configure weblogic to write logs for both nodes in  a common path and fetch that from the same path?

Comment: Please tag more carefully. You **again** tagged this as [tag:cluster-analysis] (aka: clustering), a statistical method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify the path where you want to save the logs on machine:

It can be set from the settings of your node:

My-domain->Servers->node->logging->

Enter the path and file name in text Box **Log file name:**